# ssrs show text different colour when field matches with another field

Tags: reporting-services, fonts, colors, ssrs-2008, ssrs-tablix

I have a requirement to show different text color when one field matches with another three different fields.

I have written below expression,

```
=IIF(Fields!OrderBlockLetter.Value = Fields!InstitutionBlockLetter.Value or Fields!DegreeBlockLetter.Value or Fields!AwardBlockLetter.Value, "Green", "No Color")
```

But its not working.

I am using SSRS report builder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not how the OR works.

You would need to use something like..

```
=IIF(Fields!OrderBlockLetter.Value = Fields!InstitutionBlockLetter.Value or Fields!OrderBlockLetter.Value = Fields!DegreeBlockLetter.Value or Fields!OrderBlockLetter.Value = Fields!AwardBlockLetter.Value, "Green", "No Color")
```

Comment: If I use this code it doesn't work `=IIF(
Fields!OrderBlockLetter.Value = Fields!InstitutionBlockLetter.Value, "Green",  
or Fields!OrderBlockLetter.Value = Fields!DegreeBlockLetter.Value, "Orange",
or Fields!OrderBlockLetter.Value = Fields!AwardBlockLetter.Value, "Blue", "No Color")`

Comment: In this instance use `switch()`. See here for more information: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/expression-examples-report-builder-and-ssrs